# KVM: how to resize guest VM disk via LVM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, lvm

on the Debian host nl-ams02c-kvm02 there is CentOS guest VM nl-ams02c-ispbgp02.

i resized the corresponding LVM like :

```
root@nl-ams02c-kvm02:~# lvextend -L +10000G /dev/raid50/nl-ams02c-ispbgp02
root@nl-ams02c-kvm02:~# lvdisplay /dev/mapper/raid50-nl--ams02c--ispbgp02
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/raid50/nl-ams02c-ispbgp02
  LV Name                nl-ams02c-ispbgp02
  VG Name                raid50
  LV UUID                uzftwI-kf3a-R0jl-hZXq-vSP3-MDBt-o8iXTW
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time nl-ams02c-kvm02, 2015-07-30 16:12:48 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                9.81 TiB
  Current LE             2572500
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:4
```

now disk shows correctly the rising that took effect

```
root@nl-ams02c-kvm02:~# fdisk /dev/mapper/raid50-nl--ams02c--ispbgp02 -l

Disk /dev/mapper/raid50-nl--ams02c--ispbgp02: 9.8 TiB, 10789847040000 bytes, 21073920000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 524288 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0009ede3

Device                                    Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mapper/raid50-nl--ams02c--ispbgp02p1 *       2048   1026047   1024000  500M 83 Linux
/dev/mapper/raid50-nl--ams02c--ispbgp02p2      1026048 102399999 101373952 48.3G 8e Linux LVM

root@nl-ams02c-kvm02:~# pvdisplay 
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               raid50
  PV Size               21.83 TiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              5723048
  Free PE               3041700
  Allocated PE          2681348
  PV UUID               j9Je9z-G1AN-JX7O-W03E-91l9-l80g-7Cys0V
```

the question would be;

on the guest nl-ams02-ispbgp02 (xfs filesystem)

how do i resize it ? could you please advise on the steps and how-to ?

**i have to mount it (?) first (but how ?) and then grow it with xfs_growfs (?)**

from the guest point of view, it is :

```
[root@nl-ams02c-ispbgp02 ~]# partprobe
[root@nl-ams02c-ispbgp02 ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/vda: 52.4 GB, 52428800000 bytes, 102400000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0009ede3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/vda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/vda2         1026048   102399999    50686976   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 46.6 GB, 46615494656 bytes, 91045888 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 5242 MB, 5242880000 bytes, 10240000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

[root@nl-ams02c-ispbgp02 ~]# lvs
  LV   VG     Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root centos -wi-ao---- 43.41g                                                    
  swap centos -wi-ao----  4.88g                                                    
[root@nl-ams02c-ispbgp02 ~]# df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   44G  1.9G   42G   5% /
devtmpfs                 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    7.8G  8.3M  7.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                    7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda1                497M  204M  294M  41% /boot

[root@nl-ams02c-ispbgp02 ~]# fdisk -l /dev/vda

Disk /dev/vda: 52.4 GB, 52428800000 bytes, 102400000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0009ede3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/vda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/vda2         1026048   102399999    50686976   8e  Linux LVM
[root@nl-ams02c-ispbgp02 ~]# dmesg | egrep vda
[    1.280952]  vda: vda1 vda2
[    3.645818] XFS (vda1): Mounting V4 Filesystem
[    4.411333] XFS (vda1): Ending clean mount
```

Comment: You have to boot nl-ams02c-ispbgp02 and please give us df -h, lvs, and fdisk -l from within the VM. Then we'll be able to correctly answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got a host that exports LVs to a guest, which is then using LVM again to create an LV for a filesystem.

After you `lvextend`, you've now have a large virtual disk that has a pair of smaller partitions in it. You have two options: Increase the size of the main partition, which forms the guest's PV or add a new partition as a PV to the guests VG. Personally, I'd go with the former as it's neater but if you're new to LVM, it's slightly safer to do the later, which can be done mostly all online:

1. Either:

   - In the guest: `partprobe` to pick up the new size. Verify with fdisk.
   - If `partprobe` fails: reboot guest so that it picks up the new disk size.
2. Log into guest
3. With `fdisk`, create a new extended partition. Accept the suggested start and end. Type is: 83.
4. Create new pv on new part: `pvcreate /dev/vda5` (Replace with appropriate disk and or partition
5. Add new part to VG: `vgextend centos /dev/vda5` (Replace `<centos>` with actual guest vg name)
6. Extend your the LV of your required FS: `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/centos/root`
7. Grow your FS to the size of the new LV: `xfs_growfs /dev/centos/root` (assume `/` or root)

Comment: but am not able to see the added disk space to the guest VM. that is the main issue.

Comment: Are you sure your disk size isn't being set in your Guest definition?

Comment: And I presume you've tried partprobe and/or rebooted the guest?

Comment: that is strange.. on virt-manager .. /dev/raid50/nl-ams02c-ispbgp02 includes the added size of 10TB in VirtIO Disk 1 with source name /dev/raid50/nl-ams02c-ispbgp02

Comment: yes. also rebooted. after executing partprobe.

Comment: please note that the 10TB is not part of /dev/sda1, but from /dev/sda2, guest VM has xfs filesystem and host has ext4

Comment: I've just noticed the hostname is familiar to me - a cable operator I once worked with. What are the chances!? You might want to edit your question to obscure it! I'm still thinking about your problem....

Comment: can you check `dmesg` for information about the detected size of `/dev/vda` on startup of the guest. `fdisk /dev/vda` should be showing the new size.

Comment: : big chances :)

Comment: I added the outputs above. but i think the way to go is: to use the rescue-cd, mount the lvm and resize it. what do you think ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29430/discussion-between-alastair-mccormack-and-nikos-skalis).